# LEFT JOIN для двух таблиц

Tags: sql, запрос

Помогите. Есть две таблички

[image: t1]

[image: t2]

Как сделать таблицу, чтобы отсортировало по дате одинаковой, и поделило два значения:
Пытаюсь

```
SELECT t1.cr, compl/creat
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.cr=t2.cr
GROUP BY t1.cr
```

Такой запрос не получается(

Comment: что значит "не получается" ?

Comment: Очень долго обрабатывается и в итоге ошибка

Comment: А группировка-то тут за каким хреном?

Comment: Хочу чтобы отсортировало по дате

Comment: Группировка - это не сортировка. У вас в одной таблице могут быть 2 одинаковые даты?

Comment: Деление на ноль не забудьте предотвратить

Comment: Нет, одинаковых дат не может быть

Answer (score 1):

```
select t1.cr, coalesce(cast(t1.compl as float) / cast(t2.creat as float),0)
from t1
left join
t2 on t1.cr = t2.cr
order by t1.cr
```

Это я предполагаю, что в первой таблице одному дню соответствует 1 запись, а во второй таблице может либо быть 1 запись, соответствующая конкретному дню, либо записи нет совсем, во второй таблице колонка creat не равна 0. Опять же, какая СУБД используется - не написано, может, явных преобразований чисел из int во float и не нужно.

Comment: У вас `left join` на `t2` и `coalesce(t2.creat, 0)`. Как только попадется дата, которая есть в первой таблице и отсутствует во второй - будет деление на ноль.

Comment: Нет, если даты нет во второй таблице - тогда будет 0 вместо null.

Comment: А, черт, туплю. Тогда +

Comment: субд MySQL. не прокатил данный запрос(

Comment: Ошибку выдал или данные получились не те, которые ожидались?

Comment: Вообще, глянул бегло - в MySQL вроде бы правильным будет твой изначальный запрос ( только вместо group by будет order by, естественно). Плюс можно в coalesce результат деления обернуть, чтобы null не было. Ни преобразовывать явно числа из целочисленных в вещественные не нужно, ни проверять делитель на 0 не нужно - красота.

Comment: Добрый день. Спасибо, попробую так как Вы подсказали. Еще раз спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Тебе нужно ещё просуммировать данные по каждому столбцу, т.к. не видно того, что дата уникальна, и избежать деления на ноль и null. Из-за того, что ты делаешь left join, то какие строки могут отсутствовать, и сумма от `NULL` будет `NULL`.

```
SELECT t1.cr, SUM(t1.compl) / SUM(t2.creat)
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.cr = t2.cr
GROUP BY t1.cr HAVING SUM(t2.creat) IS NOT NULL AND SUM(t2.creat) > 0
ORDER BY t1.cr
```

Comment: Вы что-то совсем странное написали из неподтвержденных предположений. Например, почему это дата, для которой во второй таблице не было значений не должна попасть в результат? А если все же не должна, то проще заменить left на inner join. И условие на то, что сумма больше 0 тоже не справедливо, возможно, она может быть меньше. И даже если она 0, еще не значит, что в результате не должно быть этой строки

Comment: я накинул на то, какие проблемы нужно решить. Конечный запрос зависит уже от ответов на эти вопросы )

Comment: деление на ноль тут не будет, просто есть у меня большая таблица, из нее я вытягиваю по запросу вот такие две таблички, и теперь мне нужно просто чтобы в одной колонке были идентичные данные,а во второй колонке деление: например для первой строки это 1, во второй строке 0.75 и тд.

Comment: Если хотим видеть всегда данные из второй таблицы, то вот:

`SELECT t1.cr, IF(SUM(t2.creat) IS NOT NULL AND SUM(t2.creat) > 0, SUM(t1.compl) / SUM(t2.creat), 'Infinity') FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.cr = t2.cr GROUP BY t1.cr ORDER BY t1.cr;`

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы в итоге вышел такой результат http://prntscr.com/hzfhna

Comment: ну так у вас такой результат будет, вопрос только в граничных случаях. Деление на ноль, если в таблице сумма `t2.creat` получилась ноль или `null` если в `t2.creat` у вас данные отсутствовали по этой дате или там были записаны `null`-ы.  Предоставьте больше данных по вашей таблице и по данным что в ней лежат. В обоих ли таблица дата уникальная, всегда ли есть соответствия, может ли в полях creat и compl быть `null`-ы?

Comment: В первой таблице могут быть нули, ничего страшного в этом нет. Во второй таблице нули не будут. Нет, NULL не будет в тех колонках